# Is there any way to add two google plists in one app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have multiple apps and I created an individual app in firebase for each app, Now I want to track analytics in one single project, So is there any way to add one google service plist for push notification and another one for tracking analytics? Please help me out to achieve this.

Comment: Are you asking how to use different plists for different apps (i.e. different targets of your project), or are you asking how to use 2 plists inside the same target?

Comment: Does this help? https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects

Comment: @KirilS. I want two plists inside the same target, One is for push notifications and another one is for Analytics.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'll check that link.